# adding a value from array to another array with same id in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays with a common key of `employee_id`and I want to insert the column `name` from my original array into the second array.

Here is what I have from my array variable named: `$result`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100001 [calculate_id] => 26 [salary] => 696.35416666667 [late_duration] => 2 [undertime_duration] => 3 [cola_duration] => 0 [date] => 2019-09-09 )
[1] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100002 [calculate_id] => 26 [salary] => 350 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 0 [date] => 2019-09-09 )
[2] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100003 [calculate_id] => 26 [salary] => 358.75 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 2 [date] => 2019-09-09 )
[3] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100004 [calculate_id] => 26 [salary] => 385 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 8 [date] => 2019-09-09 )
[4] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100005 [calculate_id] => 26 [salary] => 380.625 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 7 [date] => 2019-09-09 ) )
```

Here is my another array variable named : `$this->data_emp`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100001 [name] => John Doe )
 [1] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100002 [name] => John Dark )
 [2] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100003 [name] => John Die )
 [3] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100004 [name] => Liza Dark )
 [4] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100005 [name] => Jane Dark )
 [5] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100006 [name] => Elisse Dark ) )
```

I want to combine the two arrays into something like this result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100001 [calculate_id] => 26 [salary] => 696.35416666667 [late_duration] => 2 [undertime_duration] => 3 [cola_duration] => 0 [date] => 2019-09-09 )
[1] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100002 [calculate_id] => 26 [salary] => 350 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 0 [date] => 2019-09-09 [name] => John Dark )
[2] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100003 [calculate_id] => 26 [salary] => 358.75 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 2 [date] => 2019-09-09 [name] => John Die )
[3] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100004 [calculate_id] => 26 [salary] => 385 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 8 [date] => 2019-09-09 [name] => Liza Dark )
[4] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100005 [calculate_id] => 26 [salary] => 380.625 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 7 [date] => 2019-09-09 [name] => Jane Dark ) )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to re-index the `name` values in `emp_data` by `employee_id`, you can then iterate through `$result`, adding the `name` corresponding to each `employee_id` value in `$result`:

```
$emp_name_by_id = array_column($data_emp, 'name', 'employee_id');
foreach ($result as &$r) {
    $r['name'] = $emp_name_by_id[$r['employee_id']] ?? 'N/A';
}
print_r($result);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/j1GG6)

Comment: very great answer. this is the solution what i want